# Track ball position by image

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, bitmap, pixel

lets say that i have this image:
http://srv2.jpg.co.il/9/51c614f7c280e.png

i want to get the white ball position(x,y),
this is a verey big image,
 **then i cut the image by rectangle**.
(because when the image is smaller everything is faster),
the results:
http://srv2.jpg.co.il/1/51c616787a3fa.png

now i want to track the white ball position by his color(white=rbg(255,255,255)),
my code:

```
Public Function GetBallPosition(ByRef HaxScreenOnly As Bitmap) As Point
    For y = 0 To HaxScreenOnly.Height - 1
        For x = 0 To HaxScreenOnly.Width - 1
            If HaxScreenOnly.GetPixel(x, y) = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0) Then
                If HaxScreenOnly.GetPixel(x + 8, y) = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0) And HaxScreenOnly.GetPixel(x + 8, y + 3) = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255) Then
                    Return New Point(x, y)

                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return New Point(0, 0)
End Function
```

If the color of the **current pixel is black** and the **color of the current pixel(x+8,y+3) is white** then this is the ball 
it's working...but its verey slow, something like 200 miliseconds to track the ball position.
this is not fast enough.
there is faster way to track the white ball(**C# or VB.net**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have you a solution for you. Calling `GetPixel` is a costly process, but you use Bitmap.LockBits and manipulate / access the image data from a pointer. I took the `LockBitmap` class from **[this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp).**

I checked on the performance from what I was getting previously, which was exactly like you mentioned, around 200ms~.

Here is a picture of the result using `LockBitmap`, rescanning the image continuously with the optimized code! [image: Here's a picture]

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = new WebClient().DownloadData("http://srv2.jpg.co.il/1/51c616787a3fa.png");
    Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(data));

    LockBitmap bitmap = new LockBitmap(new Bitmap(image));
    // this essentially copies the data into memory and copies from a pointer to an array
    bitmap.LockBits();

    Color black = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    Color white = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            // GetPixel is a nice abstraction the author in the Article created so we don't have to do any of the gritty stuff.
            if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y) == black)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(x + 8, y) == black && bitmap.GetPixel(x + 8, y + 3) == white)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("White Ball Found in {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(); // copies the data from the array back to the original pointer

    Console.Read();
}
```

Hope this helps, it was certainly an interesting read for me.

### Update:

As mentioned by King, I was able to further reduce the timing for you based on the algorithm improvement. So we've gone from O(n) to O(n log) time complexity (I think).

[image: Algorithm improvement]

```cs
for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y += 3) // As we know the radius of the ball
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x += 3) // We can increase this
    {
        if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y) == black && bitmap.GetPixel(x, y + 3) == white)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("White Ball Found ({0},{1}) in {2}", x, y, stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also like to mention if you're limited to VB.NET, you could try and port most of it using something like [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com)

Comment: As well as implementing IDisposable on the Lockbitmap so that you can encapsulate it with a `using` statement. Rather than having to use `bitmap.UnlockBits()` and `bitmap.LockBits()`

Comment: using `LockBitmap` is the must-do to increase the speed. However there is a shortage in the algorithm here. We don't need to loop through `Width * Height` pixel. If we know the radius of the ball, we can calculate the best `increment` (the OP's code has the increment of 1), the best increment may be `SQRT(2) * RADIUS/2` and I think it should be better in performance (although not too much different if the image dimension is small). I guess the ball radius is about 8, so the best increment may be about 5.

Comment: That's a great point! I've added some more code and the result of this change in my updated answer.

Comment: if you don't need to tract the exact position of the ball, your updated code is OK. However, I think we need more steps to find the exact position (the center point of the ball). The first code can find this point exactly because of its one-increment. In fact increment above one can help us find any point of the ball quickly. After finding this point, we have to do more steps to find the center point. I've thhough of this idea: imagine that we find a certain point (black or white doesn't matter), from this point we draw a vertically line to find the 2 points (should be black) on the border...

Comment: ...after finding those 2 points, we'll find the medium point between those 2 points (also belongs to the vertical line we drew). From this medium point (M), we'll go ahead horizontally to find the point (should be black) on the border. Then we calculate the distance from the medium point to this point. We call that distance `dx`, if `dx < RADIUS` we will have the center point `(xM - RADIUS + dx, yM)`, if `dx >= RADIUS` we will have the center point `(xM + dx - RADIUS, yM)`. I called `(xM,yM)` as the coordinates of the mid point `M`.Inspite of these additional steps,this algorithm's still OK.

Comment: Your code looks great, I'll check it ,Thank you for the detailed explanation and the examples.